# how to migrate extjs 3 code to extjs 4 with ext.extend with 3 arguments

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have read through the migration guide, and I understand how to migrate Ext.extend for things like:

```
namespace.newClass = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel,overrides);
```

How does one migrate something (which I've done commonly and is found commonly) that looks like:

```
namespace.newClass = function(arguments){
Do some stuff;
};
Ext.extend(namespace.newClass,Ext.Panel,overrides);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.foo.MyClass', {
    extend: 'MyApp.bar.OtherClass',

    constructor: function(){
        // Call parent ctor if required
        this.callParent(arguments);            
    },

    otherMethod: function() {

    }
});
```

Comment: Does the constructor hold the function that was ran pre-extend in my example above?

Comment: Yeah, constructor is where you would put // Do some stuff.